# URL Redirect for Auth

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

My login page goes to mywebsite.com/**dashboard.html?fromauth** but if it does it without the **?fromauth** I want to redirect them to the login page. **The challenge is I cannot have a .htaccess due to provider restrictions**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor. Post CODE, not PICTURES of code

Comment: What technology are you using? You referenced javascript and java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the URL to `?fromauth=1`, and then you can use JavaScript to read the page URL:

```
var URLString = window.location.href;
var URL = new URL(URLString);
var fromauth = URL.searchParams.get("fromauth");
if (fromauth != 1){
    window.location.replace("http://www.mywebsite.com/login");
}
```

Comment: Learn more about page redirects at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help! However it redirects it if it comes from the mywebsite.com/dashboard.html?fromauth=1 Any Solution on this?

Comment: Im not understanding what the problem is. Could you go into more detail?

Comment: Even when it has the file name.html?fromauth=1 it redirects it to the auth page @Combobulated

Comment: Oh I misunderstood the question, I have edited my answer accordingly :).

Comment: Thank you so much this is a massive help!